# Changing layout options of Inno Setup Downloader Tool with Graphical Installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, inno-tools-downloader

I'm using Inno Setup and Graphical Installer with InnoTools Downloader to download an updated file during installation.

[image: See screen shot:]

**Does anyone know how to adjust the height of box the progress bar and additional details are in?**

I have successfully been able to change the other elements/controls of the installer, for example MemoReady.Height := 100

I cannot find the name of the control which the GUI for the InnoTools Downloader runs in. I can see that a Custom Page has been created here...

`itd_downloadpage := CreateCustomPage(afterID, ITD_GetString(ITDS_TitleCaption), ITD_GetString(ITDS_TitleDescription));`

I have tried the following within it_download.iss under the code:

`procedure ITD_NowDoDownload(sender: TWizardPage);`

`sender.pnlContainer.height := 100;`
`itd_downloadpage.Height := 100`
....and many other combinations.

I have looked in to the pascal source code with comes with the package and I *think* I could make the adjustment there and repackage the dll, but that is not a route I would like to go down.

I'm Lost! Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: For sure I can tell you that this would require to modify the ITD library itself (so rebuild of the ITD project would be needed). To be more specific, you'd have to modify the `TLitePanel` class from the `LiteUI.pas` unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution for this problem: http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/blog/index.php?itemid=57

I wrote a short blog article where you can download simple example and modified files.

The ITD library was rebuilt because it was covering background with it's own form.

Comment: The link in blog was also updated (sorry for double comment).

Answer (score 0):

ITD is an third party plug-in for Inno Setup, you will not find anything in Inno's manual.

Also you cannot access the ITD components as they are created by code inside the plug-in.

You need to modify the ITD library sources to view the installer correctly - as TLama said.

As I am author of Graphical Installer (http://www.graphical-installer.com/) I will look at this plug-in and make appropriate changes (ITD is written in Delphi/Pascal).